# Windows script to change DNS servers for all network adapters with *Management* in the adapter name

Tags: internal-dns

For ex: 
netsh interface ipv4 set dns *management* 10.111.253.41
netsh interface ipv4 add dns *management* 10.111.253.42 index=2

The management NIC is named: "Management Network" on one server and "Management-NIC" on another.  I need to run this script against both and set the DNS servers statically.

This will get me the adapter but how do I store it as a variable?

> Get-NetAdapter *management*

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this is what I ended up with and it works!

```
#Declaring Variables
$var1 = "x.x.x.x"
$var2 = "x.x.x.x"
$Adapter1 = Get-NetAdapter *management* | select -expand name

#Assigning primary and secondary DNS servers
netsh interface ipv4 set dnsservers name=$Adapter1 static $var1 primary
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers name=$Adapter1 $var2 index=2
Write-Host "The Primary DNS is:" $var1
Write-Host "The Secondary DNS is:" $var2
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to use a PowerShell command to get a reference to the network adapter.  The command you wrote will get the adapter that called exactly "management".  But since you just want adapters that start with the word management, you'll need to use a "where" clause like this:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'management*' }
# (which can also be shortened like this)
Get-NetAdapter | ?{ $_.Name -like 'management*' }
# (and assigned to a variable like this)
$adapters = Get-NetAdapter | ?{ $_.Name -like 'management*' }
```

So now you've got a reference to your adapter(s). Now there are a variety of ways to set the DNS servers.  `netsh` is one of them as you mentioned and likely the most downlevel OS compatible.  But if you've got Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8.1, you can use a Powershell cmdlet called [`Set-DnsClientServerAddress`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/jj590768(v=wps.630).aspx)